# how remove excess white space from a web in device mode

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This image shows how when you open from a device that space is created:

[image]

I have a web page with html and it works well viewed from a PC but when it is opened from a smartphone an empty white space is created on the right side of the page and I don't know how to fix it someone knows how to make that space disappear

Comment: Set the meta viewport and then use css media queries

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

See more here [Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag